# Maven Netbeans and Vget Integration (Can't find Vget from maven)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, wget

My porm.xml file looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
        <artifactId>vget</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>        
</properties>    
</project>
```

And My java code looks like this, But it is not adding the Vget from the maven to its import list...

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;


public class Downloader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // ex: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj6PFaDmp6c
        String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCOKysMnH50";
        // ex: "/Users/axet/Downloads"
        String path = "";
        VGet v = new VGet(new URL(url), new File(path));
        v.download();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
}
```

The Line VGet v = new ... shows an error because the vget is not imported in the code and it is not imported because, the maven won't allow me to import it, I don't know what to do with it...